# HTML CSS - transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have now: 
[image: https://gyazo.com/835ffc8fae025111c56694091ca9984c]

I want it to look like this:

[image: https://gyazo.com/b874e8ce47c91f4103fbfaa54e49a20c]

How do i can remove this transparency :/ ? i have tried to add z-index buy its not working, i think its like this div going under other site elements

```js
$('.hover-collapse').on('click', function(){
            console.log($('.hover-collapse').children(1).css('display', 'block'));
        });
```

```css
 .hover-collapse{
          position: relative }
          .block-collapse {
            box-shadow: 0px 7px 35px -7px black
            position: absolute
            display: none
            background-color: rgb(239, 236, 255)
            width: 500px
            height: 100px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
            <li class="hover-collapse">
    
                <a href="#">Szkoła</a>
    
                <div class="block-collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li>menu1</li>
                        <li>menu2</li>
                        <li>menu3</li>
                        <li>menu4</li>
                        <li>menu5</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Rodzice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uczniowie</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/logowanie/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Zaloguj się</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. What "transparency?" What is the effect you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry, i want to remove this transparency "effect". I want to completely white color on the Div   like there https://gyazo.com/b874e8ce47c91f4103fbfaa54e49a20c

Comment: You have to apply higher z-index to the dropdown than the "transparency"; we can't see styles in you snippet.. so difficult to help here.. and also make sure that the dropdown menu has no opacity setted

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNxZWx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove from class `.news-container {`
   style   `background-color: rgba(0, 56, 176, 0.1);` to fix your problem

Comment: I have add  z-index: -1 here and its ok :D Thanks a lot :)